# Comparing differences in files using grep doesnt seem to work in windows

Tags: windows, grep, cygwin

A couple of days ago I installed cygwin. I checked that grep was installed since I wanted to use it in emacs. When I wanted to obtain the difference between two files it didnt seem to work so I tried the simplest case scenario that didnt work using only the cygwin terminal.

I have two files
temp1

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

temp2

```
2
3
4
5
```

After looking around I found that the way to do it correctly was like this:

```
grep -v -f temp2 temp1
```

When I do it in cygwin I get

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

whereas if I do it in linux I get the correct output

```
1
6
7
8
9
0
```

Why could this be happening? Its probably something really silly but I cant seem to find the cause and I couldn't find something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first thought is that your files have windows line endings (CRLF) as opposed to unix/linux line endings (LF), and that is messing with grep's ability to parse the file.  try running this:

```
dos2unix temp1 temp2
```

then try your grep statement again.

extra note:

if you're going to make extensive use of cygwin, i strongly recommend you get yourself a better text editor that notepad or wordpad.

[notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is one option that easily allows you to use windows or unix/linux line endings, among a myriad of other features.

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me mad. Using the dos2unix it worked fine. Personally I use emacs for my editing needs, I think I will make a macro to change my files from now on. Thank you so much.